# Unable to create a Package in Xamarin Studio 4.0.12

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin-studio

I have a code which is developed in Mono framework & I need to do some changes into it; I have made some & now I am trying to make a package so I can deploy it on Mac. But some how its giving me error & I am not able to create a package.

It gives error saying **Solution could not be deployed: . An unspecified error occurred while running 'autogen.sh'** (the error log is provided below)

```
ERROR LOG (Tool output):
Creating packages
Package: Tarball
Building Solution: WebDisk.Mono (Debug|x86)
Building: WebDisk.Mono (Debug|x86)
Performing main compilation...
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/bin/mcs /noconfig "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll" -nostdlib "/out:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/bin/Debug/WebDisk.Mono.exe" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/glib-sharp.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gdk-sharp.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/glade-sharp.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/pango-sharp.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/atk-sharp.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.Drawing.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.Drawing.Design.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.Data.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.Web.Services.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/Mono.Posix.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/Mono.Cairo.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.Configuration.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.Windows.Forms.dll" "/r:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Assets/WebDisk.Client.BusinessLogic.dll" "/r:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Assets/WebDisk.Client.ObjectModel.dll" "/r:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Assets/WebDisk.Common.dll" "/r:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Assets/WebDisk.Client.ServiceGateway.dll" "/r:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Assets/UpdateManager.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/System.Core.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 /platform:x86 "/define:DEBUG" /main:WebDisk.MainClass /t:winexe "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/gui.stetic,gui.stetic" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Assets/FileCheckOut.png,WebDisk.Mono.Assets.FileCheckOut.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Assets/download.ico,WebDisk.Mono.Assets.download.ico" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/ClientMessages.xml,WebDisk.Mono.ClientMessages.xml" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/Theme.config,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.Theme.config" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/AddNewFile.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.AddNewFile.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/CancelCheckout.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.CancelCheckout.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/CheckInFile.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.CheckInFile.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/CheckOutFile.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.CheckOutFile.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/CheckoutFileIcon.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.CheckoutFileIcon.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/CheckoutList.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.CheckoutList.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/DeleteFolder.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.DeleteFolder.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/DeleteFolder1.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.DeleteFolder1.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/DowloadFolder.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.DowloadFolder.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/download.ico,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.download.ico" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/DownloadFile.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.DownloadFile.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/EditFileIcon.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.EditFileIcon.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/FileCheckOut.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.FileCheckOut.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/FileIcon.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.FileIcon.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/FolderNormal.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.FolderNormal.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/NewFolderAdd.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.NewFolderAdd.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/permission.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.permission.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/Property.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.Property.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/Refresh.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.Refresh.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/Rename.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.Rename.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/SelectedFolder.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.SelectedFolder.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/Thumbs.db,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.Thumbs.db" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/View.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.View.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/webdisk-connect.ico,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.webdisk-connect.ico" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/webdisk-connection.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.webdisk-connection.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/webdisk-disconnect.ico,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.webdisk-disconnect.ico" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/DefaultTheme/images/webdisk-disconnection.png,WebDisk.Mono.DefaultTheme.images.webdisk-disconnection.png" "/res:/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/App.icns,WebDisk.Mono.App.icns" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/CommonUtility.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/generated.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/MainWindow.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/MainWindow.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/AssemblyInfo.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/Menubar.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/Toolbar.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/MainClass.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/WebDiskEvents.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/MyCheckedOutFiles.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/OpenFile.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/WebDisk.OpenFile.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/ButtonData.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/User.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/OpenNewWebDisk.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/WebDisk.OpenNewWebDisk.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/ClientConfiguration.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/WebDisk.ClientConfiguration.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/FolderProperty.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/FolderInfo.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/WebDisk.FolderProperty.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/CustomViews.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/RenameDialog.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/WebDisk.Mono.RenameDialog.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/StatusBar.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/WebDisk.Mono.StatusBar.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/WebDisk.Mono.MyCheckedOutFiles.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/UploadDownload.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/UserListView.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/WebDisk.Mono.UserPermission.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/UserPermission.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/WebDiskStatusBar.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/WebDiskTrayIcon.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/CheckinFile.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/Classes/OperationQueue.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/About.cs" "/var/folders/n5/m2b64gg513q8r195mhv3kc6h0000gn/T/mdTmpDir1260862193/WebDisk.Mono/gtk-gui/WebDisk.Mono.About.cs"
Compilation succeeded - 22 warning(s)

Build complete -- 0 errors, 22 warnings

Generating Autotools files for Solution WebDisk.Mono

Creating Makefile.am for Solution WebDisk.Mono

Creating Makefile.am for Project WebDisk.Mono
Creating autogen.sh
Creating configure.ac
Creating Makefile.include
Adding variables to top-level Makefile

Deploying Solution to Tarball

You must have autoconf installed to compile WebDisk.Mono.
Download the appropriate package for your distribution,
or get the source tarball at ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/

You must have automake installed to compile WebDisk.Mono.
Get ftp://sourceware.cygnus.com/pub/automake/automake-1.4.tar.gz
(or a newer version if it is available)

Autotools files were successfully generated.
Solution could not be deployed: . An unspecified error occurred while running 'autogen.sh'
```

**Any solution regarding this will help a lot... Thanks**

CONFIGURATIONS:
Xamarin Studio 4.0.12
Mono 3.2.1

Comment: Have you installed `autoconf` and `automake` as suggested above?  I don't know if the error is related to that, but it could be worth a shot.

Comment: Sorry...I am new to Mac. What I found on mono project site is to install Mono MDK & Xamarin Studio 4.0.12, so I just did that. Isn't autoconf & automake are included in above packages? How can I install those packages?

Comment: Apparently not, according to your error message.  Download links for `autoconf`: http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/#downloading and for `automake`: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/#downloading (or use the links described in your error message).  Good luck!

Comment: I have installed autoconf & automake using this [blog](http://jsdelfino.blogspot.in/2012/08/autoconf-and-automake-on-mac-os-x.html) but it still gives me same error.